# Total number of ways in which 7 different prizes can be given to 5 students such that each student gets at least 1 prize

Tags: combinatorics

Find the total number of ways in which 7 **different** prizes can be given to 5 students such that each student gets at least 1 prize

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Have you ever heard of the stars and bars? Or combinations with repetitions as it's more properly called. In either case I think that'll give you what you need.

Comment: i tried by forming two cases - either 2 students get 1 extra prizes or 2 students get 1 prize each extra and then each of those two cases are multiplied by 7P5

Comment: i do have heard about the stars and bars method but im not sure how to use it in this scenario

Answer (score 2):

I'm considering the given prizes as well as the students as distinguishable.

First we make from the given prizes $5$ nonempty packages. Their sizes can be $(3,1,1,1,1)$ or $(2,2,1,1,1)$. In the first case we can form the $3$-pack in ${7\choose3}=35$ ways, in the second case we can form two $2$-packs in ${1\over2}{7\choose2}{5\choose2}=105$ ways.

We now have $5$ different packages that can be dealt  to the students in $5!$ ways. The total number of choices then is
$$N=(35+105)\cdot5!=16\,800\ .$$
(In certain cases $N$ could be smaller: The given prizes could be six balls of  colors blue, red, white, yellow, black, and orange, and a package containing three balls of colors blue, red, white.)